# Freely available 3D graphics resources

Tags: models, 3d

I'm primarily a programmer and always have the same issue when starting new projects: I have no artistic bone in my body.  But you can't always afford an artist.

What resources can I use for graphics?  I'm primarily looking for free 3D models in various file types.  They don't have to be elaborate, but should work for rapid prototyping.

Comment: Still looking for any resources that may be known. MD5 format is preferable, but anything will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some years ago, for the GameDev.Net "Four Elements" contest, I compiled [an extremely large list (link leads to WayBackMachine now)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101231144152/http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=324643). I haven't revisited it in some time, so probably a fair few dead links, but I'm sure there's quite a lot of live and kicking links too. It starts off with a bunch of technology links, but just scroll down. There's plenty of models and textures links.

Comment: As for MD5 specifically, I think last time I was working with MD5 I ripped them straight out of Quake 4. That's probably not helpful.

Comment: This seems to have the largest collection of anything. Accepted. =)

Comment: Sadly the link has since rotted away which is exactly why these types of questions are no longer welcome on our site. I have however fixed this by digging up the archived snapshot from WayBackMachine.

Answer (score 3):

http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/

Comment: There are some gems there, but it's unfortunately very hit-or-miss.

Comment: The nice thing with Sketchup is that the tool used to produce them is also free. Very useful if you find that "perfect" model, but it's just not orientated correctly. Whip the model up, and move the camera to the exact point and export. Unfortunately, the models are not extremely high quality though.

Answer (score 2):

www.turbosquid.com

They have free and for pay content.

Comment: I like that site, unfortunately they don't have MD5 models.

Answer (score 2):

These are a few of the model resources I used to use when working with 3D in the past.

**3D Links** is a great resource for everything with 3d. It has a long list of links to sites offerering 3d objects.

- http://www.3dlinks.com/Free_3D_Objects.cfm

Another source I used a lot to get my interior models from is **e-interiors**. You have to do a search for 3D in the Cad Library Availablity. It has hundreds of free interior objects from chairs to sinks.

- http://www.e-interiors.net/

For smaller assemblies and parts like knobs an gears have a look at **3D content central**

- [http://www.3dcontentcentral.com](http://www.3dcontentcentral.com/Browse.aspx)

**Exchange 3D** also has a list of free models

- http://www.exchange3d.com/cubecart/free-3d-models/cat_35.html

If you want 3D diamond cuts for experiments try **3D Lapidary**

- [http://www.3dlapidary.com](http://www.3dlapidary.com/HTML/Stones1.htm)

*KatsBits* has a couple of low res md5 game models

- http://www.katsbits.com/htm/models.htm

Last I want to mention **De Espona**. This collection is not free (except for a few models, available [here](http://3dup.com/models/index.vfx?dv=DeEspona)). It costs $395 for the downloadable version. But, if you're looking for an entire encyclopedia with models in various resolutions, I would recommend this one.

- [http://www.deespona.com](http://www.deespona.com/3denciclopedia/menu.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- http://www.blendermodels.org/
- http://www.3dcafe.com/

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, http://www.modwiki.net/wiki/MD5_(file_format) has information for converting many model formats (Maya, 3DS Max, Blendder, Lightwave, Softimage) into .MD5 format.

You could then take advantage of the many excellent resources mentioned in the other answers...

Answer (score 0):

[3dtotal.com](http://www.3dtotal.com) is a very popular site on 3d graphics. It offers free high quality tutorials and models. Additionally, 3dtotal distributes its own collection of texture cds - some of the best textures available.